# Group rows with appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with more than 3000 rows and I want to group those rows by a parameter in ColA. So all rows having '1' in colA should be grouped under the row above with '0' in colA. Once groups are created I want them to collapse.

Since the script will be triggered daily upon data update, I also need the before-created groups to be removed so the new ones can be properly created.

I have several scrips doing what I need but it takes forever for them to go through all the rows. Is it possible to optimize them in some way or perhaps a different approach can be used for my needs? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
    function removeAllGroups1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let d = sh.getRowGroupDepth(i + 1);
    if (d >= 1) {
      sh.getRowGroup(i + 1, d).remove()
    }
  });
}

function groupRows1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Pipeline');
  const levels = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  levels.forEach((e, i) => sh.getRange(i + 2, 1).shiftRowGroupDepth(e));
}

function collapse() {
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Pipeline');
   let lastRow = sh.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  
  for (let row = 1; row < lastRow; row++) {
    let depth = sh.getRowGroupDepth(row);
    if (depth < 1) continue;
    sh.getRowGroup(row, depth).collapse();
  }
}
```

Data Sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10BNrnAyQw89gy-Sj3CLiz4AgVtFI0AjXTvc0REGGTfY/edit#gid=113574154

Comment: Seems like reasonable code.  Maybe that's how long it's supposed to take.

Comment: Instead of going by each row, figure out what range needs to be grouped before, instead of calling `.getRange()` on each row.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a sample data? Not necessarily 3000 rows, 10 would suffice.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need one tab with a constantly updating granular dataset and another tab with a pivot table?

Comment: I thought that when Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced. To use of Sheets API is included in your goal?

Comment: @TheMaster, thanks for the suggestion! I was thinking of that but unfortunately couldn`t come up with a working solution

Comment: @NaziA, sure! here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10BNrnAyQw89gy-Sj3CLiz4AgVtFI0AjXTvc0REGGTfY/edit#gid=113574154

Comment: @MattKing, unfortunately, the pivot won`t for me in this case, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Tanaike, to be honest, I haven't used the Sheets API in an app script yet so don`t even know what to start with. Could you please give me a hint on that? Will it be possible to conditionally group rows via a Sheets API?

Comment: @Kate Bedrii Thank you for replying. The rows can be grouped using Sheets API. When I saw your script and your sample Spreadsheet, I thought that when your script is run, the processing speed might become low, and you might want to reduce the process cost. When Sheets API is used, the cost can be reduced. So I proposed to use Sheets API.

Comment: @Kate Bedrii As a sample, I posted an answer including 3 modified scripts of removeAllGroups2, groupRows2, collapse2 using Sheets API. Could you please confirm it? You can use Sheets API by enabling it at Advanced Google services. When those were not the direction you expect and I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Kate Bedrii Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to group the rows with high process speed.
- You want to delete all groups with high process speed.
- You want to collapse all groups with high process speed.

From the above goal, I thought that when Sheets API is used, the process cost can be reduced. And, Sheets API can group rows, delete all groups and collapse all groups.

#### Sample script:

Before you run this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function removeAllGroups2() {
  const sheetName = "sample";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const sheetId = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();
  const n = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, { ranges: [sheetName] }).sheets[0].rowGroups.reduce((n, { depth }) => n < depth ? depth : n, 0);
  const requests = Array(n).fill("").map(_ => ({ deleteDimensionGroup: { range: { sheetId, dimension: "ROWS" } } }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ssId);
}

function groupRows2() {
  const sheetName = "sample";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const levels = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const requests = levels.flatMap(([a], i) => Array(a).fill("").map(_ => ({ addDimensionGroup: { range: { sheetId, startIndex: i + 1, endIndex: i + 2, dimension: "ROWS" } } })));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}

function collapse2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const requests = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, {ranges: ["sample"]}).sheets[0].rowGroups.map(r => {
    r.collapsed = true;
    return { updateDimensionGroup: { fields: "*", dimensionGroup: r }};
  });
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

#### Note:

- I tested these sample scripts using your sample Spreadsheet. So when the structure of the Spreadsheet is different from your sample Spreadsheet, these scripts might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this. At first, please test them using your sample script.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionGroupRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensiongrouprequest)
- [AddDimensionGroupRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#adddimensiongrouprequest)
- [UpdateDimensionGroupRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensiongrouprequest)